# Refresh automatico PHP

Tags: php, html

Eai galera estou montando um sistema aqui e preciso que a pagina dê refresh automatico de 60 em 60 segundos, como poderia fazer?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">

Comment: Muito obrigado brother, também funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque na página esse script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      Redirect();
      function Redirect()
      {
              setTimeout("location.reload(true);",60000);   
      }
</script>
```

Em 60 segundos, ela será recarregada.

Comment: Obrigado , deu certinho hehehe Desculpe a pergunta besta, ainda sou iniciante :))

Comment: Que isso Guilherme, estamos todos aprendendo!